# Swift: new xcode project via GUI OR swift package manager CLI?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode9-beta

Im new to Swift development.

I want to use libraries that are in the Swift Package Manager format. Does this mean my project must also be in the SPM format?

So instead of creating a new project via Xcode's GUI wizard, I should be using:

`swift package init
swift package generate-xcodeproj`

Also is it possible to use SPM libraries that are written in Swift 3, but have my application code in Swift 4? Im using xcode9-beta.